# Protect files of my private flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have my own flutter package that I use throughout the git repository, I want to protect the files against any changes (re-writing). How can I do that?

I don't know how do it and there aren't many info about it in the web

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Protect from changes where? In the compiled app on user devices, in Github or some other VCS system, on your own development machine, ...?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: protect the package files against changes, for example: the package was made by me, and another programmer will use it in his project, as you know by giving ctlr + click on some function that has that package the ide takes you directly to the point definition of that function by opening the source code file and being able to view the package code, therefore I want that when such situations happen the file does not let make changes in the code, I know that those changes do not affect the repository but the idea is that programmers do not make unnecessary changes in my package to avoid bugs